# I want the Arduino to be in sleep mode by default and have a button wake it up

Tags: battery, sleep

I saw a library called LowPower_LowPowerLab that can set the Arduino in sleep mode. In their example they put the Arduino to sleep using an external button, is there anyway to invert this behavior? I want the Arduino to save battery power by being in sleep mode and then when I need it, hold a button down to keep the Arduino awake and then release the button to put it back to sleep. In their example below I have tried changing the attachInterrupt to HIGH/RISING/FALLING with no change. Also coul

LowPowerLab's Example:

```
#include "LowPower.h"

// Use pin 2 as wake up pin
const int wakeUpPin = 2;

void wakeUp()
{
    // Just a handler for the pin interrupt.
}

void setup()
{
    // Configure wake up pin as input.
    // This will consumes few uA of current.
    pinMode(wakeUpPin, INPUT);   
}

void loop() 
{
    // Allow wake up pin to trigger interrupt on low.
    attachInterrupt(0, wakeUp, LOW);
    
    // Enter power down state with ADC and BOD module disabled.
    // Wake up when wake up pin is low.
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF); 
    
    // Disable external pin interrupt on wake up pin.
    detachInterrupt(0); 
    
    // Do something here
    // Example: Read sensor, data logging, data transmission.
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing something after "Also coul".

Answer (score 2):

> In their example they put the Arduino to sleep using an external button, is there anyway to invert this behavior?

Of course. Put the Arduino to sleep in `setup` and make the button wake it up.

Some tips [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/power).

Also, I wouldn't use LOW, I would use FALLING. LOW keeps interrupting the processor, so while you hold the button down it keeps entering the interrupt, which would make it unresponsive.